# Submitting an iOS app to appstore using a different provisioning profile

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning, certificate

Is it possible to create an app built upon my certificate and provisioning, and distribute it to another entity with their own certificate and provisioning and submit to appstore?

Answer (score 0):

Yup. There wont be any problem as the code doesnt have any connection with the certificates and provisioning profiles. You can build the whole app with your certificates. These certificates and profiles are just connected with the Build. So, when you upload your app on iTunes Store, at that time, have the certificates and the provisioning profiles of the desired another entity.

Answer (score 0):

Look up Apple's codesign command-line utility, which is part of the Xcode iOS Developer tools installation.  Or type:

```
man codesign
```

from the Terminal command-line.  The XCode Build results window will show you all the parameters for this command when building your own apps.  The codesign utility will allow any developer to (re)codesign any (non-encrypted) iOS .app bundle with their own certificates and profile.  Once an app is (re)signed with that second developer's Distribution certificate, they can submit it to the App store from their own iOS Developer account.

You might want to make sure that the app's bundle ID is appropriate for the submitting developers account (using the submitting developers bundle seed, reverse DNS vendor ID and app name).